Looking for J.-C. Deville technical report from 2000
Yves Tillé's book Sampling Algorithms mentions several times a technical report by J.-C. Deville:

J.-C. Deville (2000), Note sur l’algorithme de Chen, Dempster et Liu, Tech.
rept. CREST-ENSAI, Rennes.

However, I have not had any luck locating a copy of this report anywhere. Does anyone know how I might obtain or borrow a copy?

The page https://ensai.fr/en/3-vie-etudiante/la-bibliotheque/ has contact details for the head librarian at ENSAI.

@NeilStrickland Excellent suggestion. I had spent a few minutes looking at their website but didn't find that page.

@NeilStrickland I wrote to them and they sent me a prompt and courteous reply. Unfortunately, they don't have a copy of the report.

I wrote to Yves Tillé and he sent me a scan of a handwritten draft of the report. It seems likely that this is the best one can hope for.
